# Backup in SQL Azure very slow

Tags: azure, backup, azure-sql-database, database-backups

I'm currently working on an SQL Database backup strategy in advance of porting our application to Azure. Currently we are using a SQL Server maintenance task to run a backup of our on-premise database  once every 15 minutes with a 1 hour retention (thus retaining 4 local copies). We also run a 24 hour backup which gets pushed into Amazon S3.

Now in Azure, I've so far managed to institute a backup of the primary database (to another sql server instance) using the following T-SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE targetserver.backupName AS COPY OF sourceserver.sourceName
```

The source database is approximately 3GB in size and is expanding around 5-10% per month. The problem I'm having is that the copy process is painfully slow! I initiated a copy over 30 minutes ago and it's still running! This means that adopting a 15 minute backup schedule seems untenable in Azure.

So I'm wondering if I can qualify a few things with other users:

1. Is it normal for a 3GB backup to take over 30 minutes (and counting) to replicate to another server instance?
2. Should I keep the backups on the same server as the source? I'm very nervous as a few clicks in the Azure portal could wipe out a lot of critical data! I know this is a 'black swan' event but I just wouldn't feel easy having everything running in a single server instance.
3. Is there a quicker way to backup an SQL Azure Database? I've taken a look at the [Red-Gate](http://cloudservices.red-gate.com/?utm_source=redgate&utm_medium=weblink&utm_term=sqlazurebackup&utm_content=richardmitchell&utm_campaign=cloudservices) but it seems expensive to do sub daily incremental backups.

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated!

I should add that I am happy to rethink my backup strategy entirely to be more Azure friendly. The key thing is mitigation against administrator error, e.g. dropping a load of important data due to a clumsy statement (the shorter the backup intervals the better) and a 24 hour backup pushed into a different storage method, e.g. blob container.

**UPDATE ------**

I cancelled the initial backup request after waiting 1 hour and re-initiated. The second backup completed in 5 minutes. I've now gone back to Red-Gate to take a look at their hosted backup solution.

Comment: Yes, from my experience with SQL-Azure it is normal for a 3GB backup to take about 30 minutes to replicate to another server instance.

Comment: The database has been in COPYING state for 1 hour now, is that still normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long copy database takes to run depends not only on the size of the data, but also how many transactions are being run on it at the time, so this option may not be tenable in your situation.  Now that you have a backup DB you can test this for yourself by making a backup of your backup and see how long that takes.

Your other option is to export a .bacpac file and store it in blob storage.  There are libraries for this but I don't have the reference to hand.  This will also be a much cheaper option.  I'm pretty sure this is what Red Gate are doing under the covers of their service.

Comment: Thanks knightpfhor. As I understand it, exporting to .bacpac does not produce a transactionally consistent backup. What Redgate do is run a CREATE DATABASE ... AS COPY OF ... and export to .bacpac from there. They also allow you to directly export to .bacpac which is much faster but without any guarantee of being transactionally consistent. For now I'm going with the Redgate solution as they're handling all the scheduling for us so we can focus on other areas. We can create 4 backups per day for USD 40 per month + the cost of having another db in Azure.

Comment: That's all exactly correct.  It's the trying to keep transactionally consistent that means the copy database runs slow if you have transactions on your DB.

Comment: You're right, under the surface we make use of the Microsoft Import/Export service. This is the same functionality that you see in the Azure Portal.

Microsoft did a pretty comprehensive run through of all the backup options for SQL Azure recently http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_azure_technical_support_wats_team/archive/2013/03/04/different-ways-to-backup-your-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx

I work for Red Gate and develop the solution :)

Comment: Be careful with that cost calculation, as I understand it the minimum charge for a DB is one day which resets at midnight UTC. So if you run 4 backups with CREATE DATABASE...AS COPY OF... You'll pay for 4 extra databases. If you create one of those at 23:59 UTC you'll end up paying for yet another.

Comment: That's interesting! I assumed we would only be charged for one additional db as the backup only exists momentarily and is then deleted once the .bacpac file is created, I didn't know it's per every new instance created. Richard, if multiple backups are being run in a day why not continuously overwrite the same database to save cost for the user?